# Конъюнкция строк матрицы

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть прямоугольная матрица, состоящая из 0 и 1. Необходимо посчитать конъюнкцию строк это матрицы (каждую с каждой), а затем сумму полученной в результате конъюнкции строки. Как это реализовать? вот наработки, но считает не верно...

```
//MatrQ[10][11]
//       m   n
int[] curL1 = new int[m];//сумма после конъюнкции

for (int f = 1; f < m; f++)
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (MatrQ[f][j] == 1 && MatrQ[i][j] == 1)
            {
                curL1[f] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Матрица с которой работаю

```
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

Результат ( строка 0 в расчете не участвует, и в расчетах не учитывается)

```
  CurL1 = {
    -
    3
    3
    3
    2
    2
    2
    2
    3
    2
    }
```

Comment: Где сам вопрос?

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Вам нужно в каждом столбце логически перемножить элементы? Просматривайте столбец, если в нем встретился хотя бы один 0, просмотр можно прекращать, результат будет нулевым. Если нулей нет - результат 1. Потом уже это всё складывайте.

Comment: @АндрейNOP В столбце, но с учетом того, что умножение делается для i-ой, к примеру, строки

Comment: Добавьте пример входных данных и то, что должно получиться в итоге

Comment: Как такой результат получается?

Comment: В столбце матрицы минимум 2 единицы. Считаем конъюнкцию всех строк со всеми, кроме первой (нулевой). Если единиц 2 и одна из них в первой строке - то эта конъюнкция не учитывается в конечную сумму. На бумажке выглядит легко

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие, то такое решение вам должно подойти:

```
int[,] matrix =
{
    { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 }
};
int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);
int sum = 0;
for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
{
    int res = 1;
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        res &= matrix[r, c];
    sum += res;
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Пробегаем матрицу по столбцам. Для каждого столбца выполняем конъюнкцию всех элементов (за начальное значение я принял 1, т.к. X & 1 = X). Результат по столбцу просто добавляем в общую сумму.

Comment: Благодарю за вариант. Немного позже проверю - отпишу

Comment: Скажем так - это код помог мне получить необходимый результат

Comment: Ну это же еще лучше, если вы самостоятельно разобрались и решили свою задачу :)